# Livewire: Function not called when using wire:click directive after some code in Blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm working on a Laravel project that utilizes Livewire for interactive components. I have a Livewire component with a button that triggers a function when clicked using the wire:click directive. However, I'm encountering an issue where the function is not being called when the button is clicked if the wire:click directive is placed after some code in the component.

// blade component

```
<div>
    <tr class="text-center border-top">
        <td rowspan="4">{{ $product_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <button wire:click ='add'> add</button>
    {{ $count }}
    <!-- Some code here -->
</div>
```

// function code

```
  public $count=0;
  public function add(){
    $this->count++;
     Log::info('Count incremented. New count: ' . $this-\>count);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your code and found it working. Kindly ensure that your layout file  for full-page components follows Livewire's guide -https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/components#layout-files

Answer (score -1):

It might be because you forgot to include the script assets. You can use the blade directive `@livewireScripts` or the tag syntax `<livewire:scripts />`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: i put the livewirescript before the </body> tag